# Alternate icon and title in Action

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I want to create a customized ActionBar that displays a logo for a few seconds and then changes to the title of the Fragment and then changes again to the logo and so on.

This is the piece of code that I have for the moment.

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo_nuevo);
```

Comment: I think you can use handler or alarm manager to send repeat action to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
Handler handler = new Handler(){
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //change bar code here
        handler.sendMessageDelay(msg,/** time */);
    }
}
```

or alarm manager can also get the same effect.